# Possible to interact with android service without binding?

Tags: java, android, android-service, dalvik

Is it possible to interact directly with methods in a service without binding to it? I'm moving a component in my application to a service and now it has become very unstable since binding to the service is an asynchronous operation. I know I can bind/unbind to the service in the onCreate / onDestroy methods in my activity, but I need access to this component directly in the lifecycle methods!

So, is it possible and not totally mad to start a service with the Context.startService method, save the started service instance in a global variable and then accessing it from my activity / fragments?

Comment: Then why is this a service in the first place? Activities should be loosely coupled to other components (other activities, services, etc.).

Comment: It wasn't a service initially, but new requirements about it doing its processing when the app is in the background made me move it into a service.

Comment: Then continue your redesign work to more loosely couple the UI from the service. Or, perhaps it is more that the activities should have little-to-nothing to do with the service outright, but rather with some other layer (content provider, database-plus-POJO-cache, etc.), with which the service also interacts.

Comment: This might not always be a good solution or even possible, but you could try extracting the functionality you need in the activity from the service to separate class(es) which you could use in both the activity and the service.